# Java String.indexOf API

Tags: java

I have following situation,

```
String a="<em>crawler</em> <em> Yeahhhhh </em></a></h3><table";
System.out.println(a.indexOf("</em>"));
```

It returns the 11 as the result which was the first  that it founds.

Is there any way to detect the last  instead of the first one for the code written above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [indexOf( ) and lastIndexOf( ) in Java](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=225)

and

[lastIndexOf](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks man....I thought the lastIndexOf returns the last index of the same occurrence...overlooked that part...Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

`lastIndexOf` gives you the index of the last occurrence of `needle` in the `haystack`, but the following example of finding **all** occurrences may also be instructive:

```
for (int pos = -1; (pos = haystack.indexOf(needle, pos + 1)) != -1;) {
    System.out.println(pos);
}
```

To find all occurrences *backward*, you do the following:

```
for (int pos = haystack.length(); (pos = haystack.lastIndexOf(needle, pos - 1)) != -1;) {
    System.out.println(pos);
}
```